# Only have one radio button checked at a time IN DIFFERENT forms

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

How can I have only one radio button checked at a time if they are in different forms?

Mine are in a toolbar and therefore forced into different forms.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class=red>
            Red:
            <input id=red type=radio value='Red'>
        </li>
        <li class=yellow>
            Yellow:
            <input id=yellow type=radio value='Yellow'>
        </li>
        <li class=grey>
            Grey:
            <input id=grey type=radio value='Grey'>
        </li>
        <li class=blue>
            Blue:
            <input id=blue type=radio value='Blue'>
        </li>
        <li class=lightBlue>
            Light Blue:
            <input id=lightBlue type=radio value='Light Blue'>
        </li>
        <li class=orange>
            Orange:
            <input id=orange type=radio value='Orange'>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have tried putting `<form>` in between `<ul>` and the first `<li>`, but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't see any `<form>`s at all here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them all the same `name` attribute, for example `name="color"`. Like this:

```html
    <ul>
        <li>
            Red:
            <input  name="color" id=red type=radio value='Red'>
        </li>
        <li class=yellow>
            Yellow:
            <input  name="color" id=yellow type=radio value='Yellow'>
        </li>
        <li class=grey>
            Grey:
            <input name="color" id=grey type=radio value='Grey'>
        </li>
        <li class=blue>
            Blue:
            <input  name="color" id=blue type=radio value='Blue'>
        </li>
        <li class=lightBlue>
            Light Blue:
            <input name="color" id=lightBlue type=radio value='Light Blue'>
        </li>
        <li class=orange>
            Orange:
            <input name="color" id=orange type=radio value='Orange'>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Also, while your code "works" as is (after adding the `name` attribute) I would also put all of your attribute values in double quotes, e.g. `id="red" type="radio" name="color" value="Red"`. Have a read of [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values) for some reasons why.